# Обработка и анализ аудиофайлов python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, wav

интересует следующий вопрос: у меня есть задание по обработке аудиофайлов, их этих файлов нужно вытащить следующие параметры, которые указаны ниже(параметры даны на английском) для дальнейшего написания нейронной сети на Python. Я новичок в этой теме, из интернета узнал, что нужно использовать библиотеку Librosa или parselmouth, но чтение документации ничего не дало, я так и не смог найти как вычленить данный параметры. Буду раз любой помощи, может есть еще какие-нибудь библиотеки, с помощью которых можно получить данные характеристики из аудиофайлов или ресурсы, на которых описано как с помощью библиотек указанных выше получить данные параметры. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Нужные параметры:
Frequency related parameters:

1. Pitch, logarithmic F0 on a semitone frequency scale,
   starting at 27.5 Hz (semitone 0).
2. Jitter, deviations in individual consecutive F0 period
   lengths.
3. Formant 1, 2, and 3 frequency, centre frequency of
   first, second, and third formant
4. Formant 1, bandwidth of first formant.

Energy/Amplitude related parameters:
5) Shimmer, difference of the peak amplitudes of consecutive F0 periods.

6. Loudness, estimate of perceived signal intensity
   from an auditory spectrum.
7. Harmonics-to-noise ratio (HNR), relation of energy
   in harmonic c

Spectral (balance) parameters:
8) Alpha Ratio, ratio of the summed energy from
50-1000 Hz and 1-5 kHz

9. Hammarberg Index, ratio of the strongest energy
   peak in the 0-2 kHz region to the strongest peak in
   the 2–5 kHz region.
10. Spectral Slope 0-500 Hz and 500-1500 Hz, linear
    regression slope of the logarithmic power spectrum
    within the two given bands.
11. Formant 1, 2, and 3 relative energy, as well as the
    ratio of the energy of the spectral harmonic peak at
    the first, second, third formant’s centre frequency to
    the energy of the spectral peak at F0.
12. Harmonic difference H1-H2, ratio of energy of the
    first F0 harmonic (H1) to the energy of the second F0
    harmonic (H2).
13. Harmonic difference H1-A3, ratio of energy of the
    first F0 harmonic (H1) to the energy of the highest
    harmonic in the third formant range (A3).

Comment: Вообще ни один параметр не смогли найти? Я бы начал с разбора терминов - что каждый из них означает вообще. А потом бы искал эти штуки в библиотеках. Без понимания сути терминов сложно что-то вообще искать и понимать, как это всё связано, как оно выглядит.

Answer (score 1):

Это похоже на набор фичей для аудио [GeMAPS](https://sail.usc.edu/publications/files/eyben-preprinttaffc-2015.pdf). Он достаточно распостранён и можно найти готовые решения, которые сгенерируют все 13 значений.

Например, можно поставить библиотеку [opensmile](https://pypi.org/project/opensmile/) и получить фичи для аудиофайла:

```
import opensmile

smile = opensmile.Smile(
    feature_set=opensmile.FeatureSet.GeMAPS,
    feature_level=opensmile.FeatureLevel.Functionals,
)
y = smile.process_file('audio.wav')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано:_являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_.

Comment: @0xdb, расширил ответ

Comment: Гут, поправил ответ.